# New Computer won't boot up

Tags: boot, computer-building, repair

I brought new components and put a computer together.  I installed Windows 7 (32-bit) and everything was working as it should. However my case came with two USB3 front ports I could not connect because of motherboard did not support USB3, so I swapped out the board for a new motherboad with USB3 connection.

Now I put everything back together but it won't bootup.

- "Memory Ok" light stays on.
- Motherboad LED is on.
- There is power, all fans are on but I got no display.

There is no activity in back of the systems, none of the peripheral connection in the back are working.

I have tried the following but to no avail.

- Reboot multiple times
- Unplug power and plug the power back
- Reset the CMOS battery, let it stay out for 10 minutes or more.
- Unplug all peripheral device but no luck
- Reset memory, nothing happens

The only thing I did not do was remove the CPU, but I unplugged everything else.

Comment: What does the motherboard manual say about the Memory Ok light being on?

Comment: Memory Ok light on indicate DIMM incompatibility for the motherboard.  I am using DDR3 KHX1600C9D3K2/8GX, (2x4) acccording the memory QVL it should work.

Comment: Then one or more DIMMs have probably gone bad. :( I wish that weren't the case. Some motherboards have a "Any memory will work" option, with a special button on them that you can hit to enable it. You could try that, and try reseating the DIMM(s) _again_ but other than that you may need new memory. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

I use one memory port at a time and found tha two of the four DIMM's ports were bad.  I return the system board and get one that work.